# BouncyCastle signature creation java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: xmss_SHA256ph

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pki

I am trying to create a signature as shown below, but I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: xmss_SHA256ph
```

I am using bcprov-jdk15on and bcpkix-jdk15on version 1.64 and Java 8. I have tried various signature algorithms, the latest being SHA1WITHRSA. I have also tried SHA256WITHRSA and SHA256withECDSA.

Do you know why I am getting this error? Thanks.

```
CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(getSignatureAlgorithm()).build(key);
gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new 
JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(sha1Signer, cert));
gen.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(chain));
CMSTypedDataInputStream msg = new CMSTypedDataInputStream(content);
CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false);
signatureBytes = signedData.getEncoded();
```

The stack trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: xmss_SHA256ph
at org.bouncycastle.operator.DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar:1.64.00.0]
at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar:1.64.00.0]
at com.trovare.document.pki.Signer.sign(Signer.java:162) ~[classes/:na]
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteSignature(COSWriter.java:744) ~[pdfbox-2.0.19.jar:2.0.19]
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1150) ~[pdfbox-2.0.19.jar:2.0.19]
at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:452) ~[pdfbox-2.0.19.jar:2.0.19]
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1386) ~[pdfbox-2.0.19.jar:2.0.19]
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.saveIncremental(PDDocument.java:1392) ~[pdfbox-2.0.19.jar:2.0.19]
at com.trovare.document.pdf.PdfDcoumentSigner.sign(PdfDcoumentSigner.java:167) ~[classes/:na]
at com.trovare.document.DocumentEncryptorApplication.run(DocumentEncryptorApplication.java:62) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.trovare.document.DocumentEncryptorApplication.main(DocumentEncryptorApplication.java:48) [classes/:na]
```

I created a new key store and key for each algorithm I tested, using the java keytool. Like this, for example:

```
keytool -genkey -alias docsigner -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA256withRSA  -validity 3650 -keystore keystore.jks
```

Comment: You can't just choose the signature algorithm, you must use one that is compatible with the key. It appears your key is for XMSS, a fairly new 'post-quantum' algorithm. But that should still work in BC 1.57 or higher. What's the full stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Each time I changed the algorithm I created a new key store and key, using the java keytool command.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 does the additional information give you any more clues as to what the reason may be? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered this but wasn't satisfied by the existing answers which said "just use an old version"!

In my case, I had been managing the following dependencies:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.68</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.68</version>
  </dependency>
```

After a bit of code inspection and looking at the dependency hierarchy, I saw another bouncycastle dependency was being pulled in that was out of sync, namely:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:jar:1.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.narupley:not-going-to-be-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
```

Managing the additional dependency to be consistent with the other bouncycastle ones resolved this for me, i.e. I added the following block to dependencyManagement in my POM:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.68</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

So, for anyone else who has this issue, mine was fixed by change the version of bouncycastle to 1.60.

I should point out that I tried versions: 1.63, 1.62 and 1.61 and none of the worked. This is what my pom looks like now (or parts of it anyway)

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <bouncycastle.version>1.60</bouncycastle.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
<dependencies>
```